# Laravel - Ajax (GET) : How to send json data from controller back to view

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm facing a problem here. I am trying to send the specific date to the controller (to make a where clause and send that back to the view) but I think it isn't even needed with a controller since you can also put a where clause in the view.

However, both parts are kinda impossible for me, tried everything but no result.

my ajax/view code...

```
$('.dates').click(function(){
    var date = $(this).attr('value');

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        data: {
            date: date
        },
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data.data);
        },
        error: function(xhr){
            console.log(xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
});
```

`console.log(data.data);` works, it outputs the date of a clicked day and what I need is that output (from JS) to Laravel (PHP) where clause to fetch data from the database.

my controller code...

```
public function rooster(Request $request)
{
    $currentUser = Auth::user();
    $schedules = Schedule::all();

    $data = $request->date;
    if($data){
        return response()->json(['msg'=>'Updated Successfully', 'success'=>true, 'data'=>$data]);
    }

    $dataa = $data;
    return view('pages.klant.rooster')->withDataa($dataa)->withSchedules($schedules);
}
```

my route:

```
Route::get('klant/rooster', 'KlantController@rooster');
Route::get('klant/kalender', 'KlantController@getData');
```

and then in my view, I have something like this, but obviously, it doesn't work since the variable doesn't get sent... (no errors)

```
@foreach ($schedules->where('datum', $dataa) as $value)
    {{ $value->user->name }}
@endforeach
```

I hope that someone can help me out here...

Note: I don't have that good experience in JSON/AJAX/Laravel, I'm a beginner.

Answer (score 5):

Firstly, in your AJAX request you haven't specified the `route` (or url) to send the data to:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/rooster/filter',
    data: {
        date: date
    },
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data.data);
    },
    error: function(xhr){
        console.log(xhr.responseText);
    }
});
```

You will need to add a `route` to your `routes/web.php` file. Something like:

```
 Route::get('/rooster/filter', 'MyController@rooster');
```

Secondly, in your `rooster` method you should be passing back `JSON`

```
return response()->json([
    'data' => $data,
    'schedules' => $schedules
]);
```

If the `rooster` method is not the one you should be sending the AJAX request to, just make sure the method it should go to returns a JSON response

You will then need to use JS to update the view using the `response` given back in

```
success: function(data){
    console.log(data.data);
    console.log(data.schedules);
},
```

Maybe use a JS based templating such as https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/

Comment: As I said, the javascript/ajax part works, success message is getting outputted in the console, I didn't use a URL because in my route I have it already, I need to get date variable in to the view to fetch data from database.......

Answer (score 0):

you are missing `url` parameter for ajax.

For tips : you can make new view having your where clause html logic and include it in main view  .. and render it using `view('your-view-path')->render()` inside your **rooster()**. And

Feel free to ask anything .. cheers.

Comment: I totally dont know how I should do that, I tried render() on the same view a lot of times but that doesnt work

Comment: but the problem isn't that, I want to use that variable in my laravel where clause (from js to laravel) idk how.

Comment: @Swiggity have you specified Url for ajax request?

Comment: yes I have it added now but as I said, ajax/laravel works, from ajax it sends the date to the controller and returns it to the view and outputs the right date. I want to use that date in a where clause thats my only problem and I totally don't know how. Tried with jquery but get stuck with database relations (dunno how to do user_id->user->name in json...)

Comment: Do your where part in controller and render it to view

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.butto').click(function(){
    var date = $(this).attr("data-id");
    //var date = $(this).attr('value');
$.ajax({
  url: '/ajax/GetContent',
  data: { date: date },
  type: "GET",  
  success: function(data){ $data = $(data);      
  $('#clear').hide().html($data).show();
   }
  });
});

//controller
public function index3(Request $request){
        //$search = 'fffffffff';
        //$search = $request->date;
        // $search = $request->input('search');
        $user = Auth::user();
        $id = $request->date;
        //$search  = moneyuser::where($where)->first();
        $search = moneyuser::where('name', $user->name)->where('email', $user->email)->where('id', $id)->paginate(3);

        return view('student.lis')->with('search', $search);
    }
    
    // Rout
    // change Page by Ajax
Route::get('/ajax/GetContent', array(
    'uses'  =>  'StudentController@index3'
  ));
```

```html
 
<a data-id="{{ $student->id }}" class="btn btn-primary butto">view</a>
```

Comment: Please edit and add some text explanation, not only code.